# How to select multiple rows from different tables using MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select, union

I have 4 tables. From `table1`, I would like to select `postID`, `status`, and `data`. From `table2`, I would like to select `postID`, `status`, and `update`. Both `table1` and `table2` share 2 columns, which are the `postID` and the `userID`.
`Table3` has a column `postID` which is common to `table2` and `table2`.

I would like to query data from table1 and table2 based on the `userID` from the user table, then use the `postID` to query data from table3.

```
$sql = "((SELECT `postID`, `status`, `data`
    FROM `table1`
    LEFT JOIN `users` 
    ON users.user_id=table1.userID 
    WHERE table1.userID=:userID 
    AND table1.active=:active)
    UNION 
    (SELECT `postID`, `status`, `update`
    FROM `table2`
    LEFT JOIN `users` 
    ON users.user_id=table2.userID 
    WHERE table2.userID=:userID 
    AND table2.active=:active
    ORDER BY table1.postID DESC))
AS tab12
LEFT JOIN `table3`
ON table3.postID=:tab12.postID
WHERE table3.active=:active";
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(":userID", $userID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue(":active", $active, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
```

How do I select only some columnsfrom table3--status, update, timeDate--then associate the results to the previous query? Like:

```
$sql = "SELECT `status`, `update`, `timeDate` 
FROM `table3` 
WHERE postID=:tab12.postID
AND active=:active";
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(":postID", $postID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue(":active", $active, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for assistance.

Comment: The 1st query doesn't parse, the outermost FROM ... has no SELECT. [mre].

Answer (score 0):

```
Select result.PostID, result.Status, result.data, T2.Status,                 
result.update, user.status, user.update, user.timeDate
from (Select T1.PostID, T1.Status, T1.data, T2.Status, T2.update
from table1 as t1
union table2 as T2
where T1.UserID = T2.UserID) result
union user 
where result.PostID = User.PostID
```